# "twin" axes without shared axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to have two axes in matplotlib, sharing the same frame, but without link between any axis. Just like ax.twinx() or ax.twiny()...except that I want neither x nor y axis to be shared. Is this possible?

Edit: So basically what I want is two superimposed subplots, sharing the same frame but with independent coordinates, and such that the top one does not hide the bottom one.

Comment: What do you mean by "no link between any axis"? Do you mean you want two different subplots rather than twin axes on one subplot?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it: just use both twinx and twiny!

```
ax1 = axes() #or anything
ax2 = ax1.twinx().twiny()
```

This way `ax1` and `ax2` share no axis but are on the same subplot.